# Mongoose Populate() replaces array with object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-populate

My schema looks like this

```js
Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course' })
  courses: Course[];
}
```

```js
@Schema()
export class Course {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop([{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }])
  participants: User[];

  @Prop([{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Lesson' }])
  lessons: Lesson[];
}
```

what i'm trying to achieve is to get an array of courses that a specific user is signed up for. The way Im trying to do this looks like this.

```js
async findUserCoursesByUserEmail(email) {
    const user = await this.userModel
      .findOne({ email })
      .populate('courses')
      .exec();

    return user.courses;
  }
```

But in response i get an object like this, but it should be an array.

```json
{
    "lessons": [],
    "participants": [
        "6157a5ba06afba420464fb65"
    ],
    "_id": "6157a5ac06afba420464fb61",
    "name": "Matematyka Rozszrzona",
    "__v": 1
}
```

The user object looks like this.

```json
{
        "_id": "6157a5ba06afba420464fb65",
        "name": "Jacob",
        "email": "test@test.pl",
        "courses": [
            "6157a5ac06afba420464fb61",
            "6158d64891be3f50f85bef0a"
        ],
        "__v": 2
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated cause i'm stuck for quite some time with this one.

Answer (score 0):

as per [nestjs/mongodb docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection) change the:

```
@Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course' })
  courses: Course[];
```

on your **UserSchema** to:

```
@Prop({ type: [{mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course'}] })
  courses: Course[];
```